# How to use the right menu_tree and menu_link depending on region

Tags: routes, theming

How can I have specific menu_tree and menu_link for specific region?

Example:

left region will have his own [menu_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7) [menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7) which will be different from the right region.

How can I achieve this?

Do I need to build a custom module?

If I use [template_preprocess_region()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_region/7) , how can I call [menu_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7) and [menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7)?

Thanks in advance

----------- UPDATE ----------------------

I've seen that [preprocess_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7) gives back "region" and "module". Is there anyway to use the different menu_link() and menu_tree() depending on the region and module?

Answer (score 2):

To theme only specific regions within your drupal page simply filter your css by prefixing your class with the class or id of the region in question. You can find the region by inspecting HTML output. I use chromes inspector which is accessed via inspect element within contextual menu.

```
#region-sidebar-first .menu_tree menu_link_my_class { css }
```

and if you want a different style for the right hand sidebar

```
#region-sidebar-second .menu_tree menu_link_my_class { css }
```

Comment: oops, just reread this. Not sure that my answer was too relevant.

Comment: It seems the right answer to me: `menu_tree()` doesn't get any parameter saying in which region the menu is being rendered.

Comment: But I need to override the ul classes or replace ul with ol or with divs. I need to do it region by region.

Comment: mmm, perhps it was relevant after all. Why do you need to replace the markup? Can you ul some markup and what you are trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Nope, I need to add specific classes for menu and sub menu.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`menu_block`](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module together with [`hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7)

Comment: This will work block by block, I want region by region.